# Bulk import hyphenation dictionary into InDesign

Tags: text, adobe-indesign, hyphenation

I’m working on a bringing several large books into a InDesign, that were previously sent in LaTeX. One requirement is that I migrate the hyphenation list/dictionary (close to 1000 words) into InDesign. I know I can manually place a discretionary hyphen when a word breaks where I don’t want it to, or insert one where I want it to break... but, is there a way to do that based on a list of specific hyphenation rules? I’ve currently got the list in two formats:

```
.abo2
.ace4
.ace2t3
.a2ch4
.ac5t2iva
.a2ct
```

And:

```
Ab-bre-via-tion
Ab-bre-via-tions
Abingdon
ad-equate
ad-equate-my
```

Comment: Is there a way based on the patterns in the first example to generate the second list if you have the words without dashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add those to your "User Dictionary"
Check out the documentation here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/lv/indesign/user-guide.html/lv/indesign/using/spell-checking-language-dictionaries.ug.html

If you're in a hurry, skip to "Add words to dictionaries".

Then check out "Export a word list" and "Import a word list"

Note that the exported word list is plain text with tildes marking the hyphenation points.